# i have appointment for "Elektiv-Ambulanz" (Germany)

Tags: surgery

I have an appointment for "Elektiv-Ambulanz", what does it mean I want to do my surgery as an outpatient instead of inpatient.

Comment: That's what Elektiv-Ambulanz means.

Comment: @careyGregory what do you mean , do i need to stay overnight in hospital ?

Comment: Call your doctor and ask.